# Why do these draggable elements sometimes leave space when snapping? (jQuery UI)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

This is a strange, inconsistent issue that I don't think has been asked yet on this site. I have draggable elements that snap to each other. Sometimes, they snap but leave a small space (around 1px) so they aren't actually touching. If you play around on the jsfiddle below, at least one of the elements are bound to do this. I have tried specifying a width for `.word` in px, and using all the same letter inside the element. It's not always the same elements that have the space, and sometimes one space is slightly bigger than another, as you can see in these screenshots:

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxy0i.png)

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQtkO.png)

I'm quite stumped and would appreciate any ideas!

https://jsfiddle.net/ruemca/tdm3c51x/1/